Difference between "play your cards right" and "on the right track"
Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms 'play your cards right' and 'on the right track'? The definitions in the Cambridge Dictionary are:

play your cards right: to do the correct things to achieve the desired result
on the right track: doing something correctly or well


These idioms are also metaphors. A game of cards can be won if you play it "right" (right=well) because your hand is good, but if you make a mistake, you will lose the game. A track is similar to a road, if your destination is not within sight you might feel you are on the wrong track, but keep going and your destination will eventually appear.

You seem to be citing the Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary, which is intended for use by students for academic writing. But I wouldn't expect to commonly see either phrase in academic writing. If you're interested in general colloquial English, you should get a different dictionary; such a dictionary will probably have more information on how to use idioms such as these. (And if asking a question here, you should say whether you're interested in academic writing or colloquial speech or something else.)

If you stay on the right track,  you will get the job.
If you play your cards right, you will get the job.
The first means, basically, do what's right to get the job.
The second means, you use your existing skills to get the job.
They are not 100% synonymous.
The first is more about following a specific path.
The second is more tactical/strategic.

Also, "If you stay on the right track" implies you are already doing something right.  "If you play your cards right" does not

@Kevin No, it does not. It's conditional. It would have to be something like: Continue on the right track or continue staying on the right track...

How can you stay on something that you're not already on?

Lambie, @Kevin is correct - "stay on the right track" means you are already doing the right thing

The encouragement that you are on the right track means you should continue doing what you're doing because you're already doing things properly now. You have made a good start. You are headed in the right direction.
By contrast, if you play your cards right is a mix of encouragement and warning. It indicates that you have been lucky so far. You have been dealt a pretty good hand but you could screw things up. Success or failure will depend on your future actions.

On the right track needs be in front of it to correspond grammatically with play your cards right.
"[Something good will happen] if you play your cards right" refers to 'doing the right things' in the future.
If we say that someone "is on the right track", they are already doing the right things, though they haven't yet achieved the desired result.

I might think that 'playing your cards right' could cover being one or more of astute, cunning, or alert in the short term (using intelligently the advantages you have), while 'being on the right track' might cover a sort of solid long-term progress.

@Kate Bunting
So you mean that if we say "if you be on the right track" (future)
or someone "plays his cards right",
are these two sentences wrong?

When I met my girlfriend's father, I played my cards right by saying I supported the same soccer team and political party as him, and that I liked his kind of rock music.  Now I'm on the right track to marry his daughter.

Another way to put Kate’s point is that on the right track is a state, whereas play your cards right is an action (In case this syntactic difference is relevant to your question).

"If you are on the right track,." Which two sentences?

The two phrases are related, but there is a difference.
"on the right track" relates to past actions; you have done the right things.  It also has the implication that you have not yet achieved the goal.
"play your cards right" relates to potential future actions; if you do these things, you will achieve the goal.

Merriam Webster example: Diagnosing and addressing myopia early is important to ensure a child’s development is on the right track, Ghasia said.
—Adrianna Rodriguez, USA TODAY, 19 Sep. 2024
